# Magento Cloud Docker 2.4.6-p2 on ./bin/magento-docker ece-deploy

Tags: magento2.4, deployment, cloud-docker

I am facing this error:

```
Module 'Magento_AdobeCommerceEventsClient':
  Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\AdobeIoEventsClient\Model\Credentials\CredentialsFactory, Magento\AdobeIoEventsClient\Model\Credentials\CredentialsFactory::__construct(): Argument
  #1 ($credentials) must be of type array, null given, called in /app/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121.
```

running `./bin/magento-docker ece-deploy` on the setup upgrade step.
I have already checked the encryption key in the app/etc/env.php in the Docker environment, that should not be the problem. Thanks!